# HTTPClient initialize in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

```
class ApiService() {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient()

    suspend fun fetchData(): List<ProductModal> {
        return httpClient.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1")
    }

}
```

I try to get the data from above API in KMM but when I initialized `HTTPClient()` I'm getting error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnZhr.png)

How to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Your ApiService class isn't initiating you might doing something wrong while calling ApiService from your error log